# sending an image from client to server-side in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, backend

I am trying to upload an image to the server but  keep getting an error in the chrome console "POST http://localhost:3000/images 500 (Internal Server Error) @ main.js:19".

it looks like he server side of my application is not receiving the image.when I try to access the file on the server I get undefined([Error: Input file is missing]). When I post using html without the client-side javascript, the image is posted successfully. However, I want to post the image using the client-side js. Can someone help me know what I am doing wrong

main.js

```
const form = document.querySelector('form')

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
e.preventDefault()

const files = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files
let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
const formData = new FormData()


let file = files[0]
console.log((file));
formData.append('files[]', file)

req.open("POST", 'http://localhost:3000/images');
req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'image/*');
req.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'image/*');
req.send(formData);
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

<title>Upload Files</title>
</head>

<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple />
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-center" 
id="queryButton"> Query </button>
</form>

<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending `files[]` as an array in a FormData object, but you're setting the request content-type to `image/*` . In other words, you're telling the server you're sending an image, but you're actually sending form data, which is not the same format.

I don't think you need to set the content-type; when you send a FormData object, the XHR will set the type correctly on its own. So try removing the content-type header completely. If that doesn't work, try using a content-type of `multipart/form-data` instead.

Comment: Thank you for you response. However, I still get get a 500 error when I do one of the two things you mentioned. when I remove  content-type header completely and/or changing content-type to multipart/form-data instead still give me the error

Comment: I managed to get it to work. Much of it was due to what @IceMetalPunk mentioned, but I also had to a lot other stuff. Complete code for the project is [here](https://github.com/furahadamien/jsonSilo/blob/f4d56c25f358117db6a7360df952fc9aa1db1a2d/COMPLETE_SILO/web/main.js#L24), including the server side code